# How to raise a specific exception in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception

I'm trying to handle an input exception in my query in PostgreSQL but I can't find the exact error to raise the exception.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_score(t integer, seas varchar(9)) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    ....

EXCEPTION
    WHEN syntax_error THEN
    RAISE INFO 'Not a valid input';

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to handle two input errors: the error for the integer, the error for the varchar.

Comment: You won't get an exception inside your code, because the function will never be called, if you pass invalid values to it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so, I can't handle input errors?

Comment: No, because the parameter values are validated by Postgres **before** calling your function. You can be 100% that the parameter `t` will contain a valid integer and that the length of the parameter `seas` will never be longer than 9 characters. That's the whole point of having data types.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention On what conditions you want integer t and varchar seas t to fail. You  can also mention them using check constraint. There are no predefined errors to validate integer and varchar except checking their type.

Comment: I want to handle input syntax errors. How can I do that?